# css Autosize table header with glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to autosize a column by its header size which includes a glyphicon right aligned?

E.g.:

```
      <th class='autosize'>Col1 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right' aria-hidden='true'></span></th>
```

And the style:

```
<style>
  .autosize {
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
</style>
```

Pushes the glyphicon to the second column.

Full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .autosize {
      width: 1px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 1px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='autosize'>Col1 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-sort pull-right' aria-hidden='true'></span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you mean by autosize? give it the size of the header? a % of it?

Comment: I mean auto-size to header text as supposed to body content.

Comment: If you take the glyphicon out it works

Answer (score 0):

Gee always the way you spend hours changing css to see what works and by posting here I had the light turned on, all I had to do is remove the pull-right class out of the glyphicon